# Use the start-process command to get the return value of the running program

Tags: powershell

Using the .bat file code below, I can get the value returned after running the program.

```
"C:\Program Files\www\www.exe" /start "/My app/abc" && echo %ERRORLEVEL% > c:\ResultCode.txt"
```

How to use the powershell code to achieve the same functionality

I use the code below and I didn't get the result.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\www\www.exe" -ArgumentList "/start `"/My Processes/abc`"" -RedirectStandardError "c:\ResultCode.txt"
```

Comment: `(Start-Process -FilePath "..." -ArgumentList "..." -PassThru).ExitCode > "C:\ResultCode.txt"`

Comment: PowerShell captures the result of native commands in the [$LastExitCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) variable.  Also, `Start-Process` is asynchronous unless you use the `-Wait` parameter, so if you immediately try to get `$LastExitCode` after calling `Start-Process` it may not be set yet if the process is still running.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers  C:\ResultCode.txt is empty in the file, should contain the number 0

Comment: Add `-Wait` to the statement, as boxdog mentioned.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers thanks, Run Successful!
```
(Start-Process -FilePath "..." -ArgumentList "..." -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode > "C:\ResultCode.txt"
```